How to disable the touch elements in other parts of a display in the APL templates in an Alexa Skill?
So we have created an alexa skill which plays the latest news from WPI. But in viuals part when we click anywhere on the Alexa template in the Alexa Skill, it stops speaking so can someone please help us to disable the touch interactions on other parts of the display apart from the buttons.
We tried using touchwrapper and set state but it didn't work.
